# Why is VS2015 showing pending changes while SourceTree doesn't?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, tfs, atlassian-sourcetree

I've just started working on a new project where we use VS2015 with TFS and Git for our repositories. Several times now Visual Studio has shown me a pletora of files checked out with pending changes, while most of these files don't have any changes.

I thought about line endings at first, but then I noticed that SourceTree only showed the files that actually did have changes. Running git -diff also doesn't display these unchanged files, only Visual Studio does.

Something else I noticed after my last commit (done in SourceTree), the files that I committed where still displayed as having pending changes in Visual Studio. After restarting VS the files are still on the pending changes list.

One colleage has the same issue, while three others have never experienced this. All four of them have been working on this project for much longer than me.

I've spend a few hours googling for answers and found many cases that seem similar at first but none have a working solution for me.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be causing this issue for me and what I might do to prevent it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: added some specs
OS: Win Server 2012 R2 Standard (v. 6.3.9600)
VS: VS Enterprise 2015 (v. 14.0.23107.0 D14REL)
SourceTree: 2.1.11.0

Thanks,
elloco

Comment: Almost certainly line endings.  VS 2015 (RTM) is especially sensitive to these problems.  How are your line endings configured?  What version of VS 2015?  Have you installed the latest updates?

Comment: I added my OS en VS version to the question. Sadly, I'm not running the latest update of VS, because we have to work on a very secure environment where everything is restricted. I can't run the update myself and have not gotten permission yet to have it installed by a system administrator.
I honestly don't know how my line endings are configured. I don't know how/ where to check this.

Comment: This would be configured in `.gitattributes`.  I'm reasonably certain that you have files checked in with line endings that do not match the promises made by `.gitattributes` (or the suggestions made by `core.autocrlf`).  Visual Studio 2015 is not happy when these do not match.  This is all significantly improved by VS 2015 Updates.  I encourage your system administrators to understand that software updates fix bugs _and_ security holes and should be treated like the critical updates that they are.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Well it seems I've managed to convince them that updates are important, they are downloading the installer now.  However the colleage who's having the same issue is using update 3 already so I'm only moderately hopeful this will change anything ;-)

Comment: Where can I find these .gitattributes or core.autocrlf? I'm very new to git, on previous projects I've always used Team Foundation Version Control

Comment: @elloco999 The .gitattributes  file is located in the root of git repository.  And different "View Options" set between VS and SourceTree may also a reason, please check that, in VS, on the Pending Changes page try selecting "Included Changes" -> "View Options" , SourceTree Show only : Pending, conflicts ... etc

Comment: I have VS2015 update 3 installed now and have not seen any irrelevant files under pending changes since. So hopefully that fixed it. Thank you @Edward Thomson for that suggestion!

Comment: @Andy-MSFT My .gitattributes file doesn't exist, it's not in the root of the repository. In VS I can't find any settings/ options related to pending changes. I looked in the options menu (Tools -> Options, nothing related to pending changes) and checked the both the "Changes" and "Settings" page in Team Explorer but no settings here that allow me to select what should be included in the pending changes. Could you please elaborate where I can find these settings? Thanks.

Comment: @Andy-MSFT That's okay, glad I wasn't missing some options :) I was waiting to see if the problem really has disappeared before posting the solution. I haven't had any problems since I installed update 3 so I will do so now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Edward Thomson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729881/edward-thomson) for suggesting to install update 3 for VS2015, this seems to have done the trick for me. No more unchanged files in my list of changes.